# Equivalence Relations on Set of Ordered Pairs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the relation on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, that is elements of this relation are pairs of pairs of integers, such that $((a,b),(c,d)) \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $a-d = c-b$. Can anyone give me a start on how to solve it to be transitive, reflexive and symmetric?

Comment: Note that $a-d=c-b$ if and only if $a+b=c+d$; that’s an easier way to test whether two pairs are in the relation.

Comment: Because you are only asking for a start, it is not as vital, but it is usually a good idea to show what you have tried and where you are confused.

Answer (score 1):

- Reflexive: $\forall (a,b):\Bigl[(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z\times Z} \to \bigl((a,b),(a,b)\bigr)\in R\Bigr]$
- Symmetric: $\forall (a,b,c,d): \Bigl[\bigl((a,b),(c,d)\bigr)\in R \leftrightarrow \bigl((c,d),(a,b)\bigr)\in R\Bigr]$
- Transitive: 
  $\forall (a,b,c,d)\exists (e,f): \Bigl[\bigl((a,b),(e,f)\bigr)\in R\land \bigl((e,f),(c,d)\bigr)\in R \leftrightarrow \bigl((a,b),(c,d)\bigr)\in R\Bigr]$

Show that these properties hold (or not) when $\Bigl[\bigl((a,b),(c,d)\bigr)\in R \Bigr]\iff\Bigl[ a-d=c-b\Bigr]$

---

*Hint:* $[a-d=c-b] \iff [a+b=c+d]$

Answer (score -1):

**Reflexive:** $((a,b),(a,b))\in R$ since $a-b=a-b$.

**Symmetric:**  Suppose that $((a,b),(c,d))\in R$ since $a-d=c-b$, hence  $c-b=a-d$. So  $((c,d),(a,b))\in R$.

**Transitive:**  Suppose that $((a,b),(c,d))\in R$ and $((c,d),(e,f))\in R$. Then  $a-d=c-b$ and  $c-f=e-d$, and hence $a-d+c-f=c-b+e-d$ which implies that $a-f=e-b$. So we have that $((a,b),(e,f))\in R$